# Google Drive API - authorize httplib2.Http() with stored credential

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code and maybe you can help me, here's my situation:

I'm making a simple command line tool to upload file on google drive, all its working if no credential is store and I'm using a fresh token, but if I use a stored data the upload is not working, here's my code:

```
flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(JSON,
                               scope=OAUTH_SCOPE,
                               redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
storage.put(credentials)
```

I'm using a flow object to retrieve obtain the link to authorize my app, when I have the code I pass it to the step 2 and I store the credential, then i crate a new build

```
drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http)
```

now if I use this code it works but if I try to use

```
storage = Storage('credential.dat')
credentials = storage.get() //I also tried locked_get(), same result
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
```

and the

```
drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http)
```

isn't working anymore.

The data are writtend in the credential.dat so this is not the problem, any idea?

thanks!